# Is there a way to avoid putting namespaces on t function?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm adding the `react-i18next` library to our project and by now it works great (and it's a really great tool), different files, namespaces, and all... But I wanted to know if there's any way to avoid this code:

```
t('namespace2:Text in original language')

or

t('Text in original language', { ns: 'namespace2' })
```

if I've already loaded namespaces with `withTranslation(['namespace1', 'namespace2'])` function. As both namespaces are loaded, can the t function look for the text in both of them, or do I always need to specify the namespace if it's not the default or the first one in the `withTranslation` argument.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc#loading-namespaces) this function works exactly how you described.
So, yes, if the function doesn't use default translation you always need to provide namespace.

Comment: that's what I thought... I wish there was a way to avoid that, but it's OK 